# How to design ackermann steering with lego wheel bearing front?

Tags: building, technic, steering, mechanical

I wanted to use a steering system based on the 11949 part:

[image]

But I am not sure how to use it in an [ackermann system](https://mindstormspodcast.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/ackermann/) - I would like to be able to have drive and suspension on the wheel, and this piece seems like the only "reasonable" solution for combining the two into something that is relatively compact + sturdy, so is there any possible way using this piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation using this exact part: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfZaAf9Mv_E) [image: Image of Ackermann steering with 11949].

There are also several other solutions with different pieces if you need more inspiration or explanation: [Animated GIF](http://bricksafe.com/files/blakbird/Technicopedia/animations/ackerman.gif), [4 wheel steering](http://www.technicopedia.com/8880/8880csteering.jpg), [Top-down view](https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5228/13963499735_0534d14261_b.jpg).

Comment: Err.. In that top-down view, the turned wheels are parallel, not Ackermann

Comment: Close to paralell, but not exactly. You can see more clearly if you check the length of the steering rods compared to the main support beams that the rods are 1-1 stud shorter.

Comment: Ah, [your right](http://content.screencast.com/users/slapshot136/folders/Jing/media/63e3d056-a4b4-49d9-b7fa-b9106d0e2cab/2015-07-13_1336.png) - but what exactly is that wheel hub from the top-down view image or the animated gif, as it's not the one with dual pre-attached knobs like the one I was thinking of (and I don't think the video one actually shows ackermann steering either)

Comment: The setup shown in the gif uses the 8880 Supercar's wheel hubs, the first item in this inventory: http://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/technic/model/traffic/lego-8880-super-car/ The top-down view seems to use wheel hubs built from individual pieces. The ball joints are obscured by the support beams so I can't say for sure whether they are a single piece or built but the steering linkage is clearly built from individual pieces.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ackermann system the lines through the rotating point of the wheel hub and the trackrod joint intersect on the rear axle. This works when the trackrod lenght is shorter than the hub turning point distance.

[image: track rod length]

For this part to work, you need to have a fixed ratio between axle track and wheelbase. So a long narrow car won't work and a short, wide car won't either. Find the ratio by extending the line with a thead or string.

Comment: Not what I am looking for, you failed to mention the 11949 part